# Parse a SELECT query and get the JOINS with JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

Using JOOQ, is it possible to parse an SQL query and then obtain the parts of the query? Fields, From, Joins, Where... Something like that:

```
String sql = "SELECT x.a, x.b, y.c
FROM my_table x
LEFT JOIN other_table y
   on x.a = y.a
WHERE x.a > 1000";

SelectQuery<Record> query = (SelectQuery<Record>) context.parser().parseSelect(sql);
query.getFrom();
query.getFields();
query.getJoins();
query.getWhere();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jOOQ 3.15, you cannot access the internals of the jOOQ expression tree. There is a big project on the way to re-design these internals to make them publicly accessible precisely for this use-case:

- Project: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/projects/2
- Main issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9163

Until then, you need to either work around this by using reflection, putting some logic in the `org.jooq.impl` package to access package-private internals on the classpath (not possible on the module path), or by patching jOOQ - each at your own risk.